# Bluetooth peripheral has null UUID

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

I'm trying to connect a BTLE peripheral to my iOS app but the CBConcretePeripheral object that is sent to didDiscoverPeripheral has a null UUID.

This is the info from the CBConcretePeripheral Object retrieved on an iPhone 5.

```
<CBConcretePeripheral: 0x20043eb0 UUID = (null), Name = "Wahoo HRM V1.7", IsConnected = NO>
```

This works for some devices but not others.

This is the info from the CBConcretePeripheral Object retrieved on an iPhone 4s.

```
<CBConcretePeripheral: 0x1dde9720 UUID = <CFUUID 0x1dde9400> 5147BE71-E894-0152-5669-D640CA5E321C, Name = "Wahoo HRM V1.7", IsConnected = NO>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple have chopped and changed a bit with this, it depends on the version of iOS.  I believe it relates to [a privacy leak](http://www.guardian.co.uk/uk/2008/jul/21/civilliberties.privacy).

Some versions of iOS don't provide a UUID until after you connect to it, at which point you discover the same peripheral for a second time.  The `CBPeripheral` object you are passed remains the same, so you can use that to determine if you are having your information updated about an existing peripheral or if it's a new peripheral.  The documentation isn't great for CoreBluetooth, but there is additional information to be gained by reading the framework headers, and if I recall correctly, the iOS 7 documentation on CoreBluetooth is improved.